# MS Dynamics CRM: Entity name covers drop-down arrow, automatically re-label?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

We've just set up Dynamics CRM 2013. We're using the Outlook 2010 plug-in. A new entity has been created called "Projects," in which the users give the project a name (which is fairly long: Typically something like "2014 Project Name Client Name") and we assign activities and track emails to that project. The problem is that the project name in the blue bar doesn't truncate; instead it spills over the drop-down arrow (which lets you see related activities, contacts, etc) and is un-clickable. Logging in through the web interface, it truncates properly. Is there a way we can force it to truncate after a certain amount of letters, or use the ProjectID field for that label instead of the name?  I'm fairly new to Dynamics so a simple solution would be much, much preferred.

A screenshot with an arrow pointing to the over-running field:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when using IE8. In IE9, the long name is truncated properly so the related button/link/whatever it is works as expected. MS unlikely to fix this issue in IE8 just fyi. If it's a custom entity, the primary key field will be the name and that field is used in the UI when it wants to show a record. So you have two options. Change the browser version or only use short names.